# How I can create a FTP-only account, in FreeBSD?

Tags: freebsd, login, ftp

I created an account to be used only for FTP sessions:

```
# adduser
Username: test
Full name:
Uid (Leave empty for default):
Login group [test]:
Login group is test. Invite test into other groups? []:
Login class [default]:
Shell (sh csh tcsh bash rbash nologin) [sh]: nologin
Home directory [/home/test]:
Home directory permissions (Leave empty for default):
Use password-based authentication? [yes]:
Use an empty password? (yes/no) [no]:
Use a random password? (yes/no) [no]:
Enter password:
Enter password again:
Lock out the account after creation? [no]:
Username   : test
Password   : *****
Full Name  :
Uid        : 1002
Class      :
Groups     : test
Home       : /home/test
Home Mode  :
Shell      : /usr/sbin/nologin
Locked     : no
OK? (yes/no): yes
adduser: INFO: Successfully added (test) to the user database.
Add another user? (yes/no): no
Goodbye!
```

But when I try to login to the account I get the message:

```
530 User test access denied.
Login failed.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User's shell has to be in /etc/shells. I think in your configuration /usr/sbin/nologin doesn't figure in this file. Change shell for your user to f.e. /usr/bin/passwd (first ensure it's in /etc/shells) and it should work.

Comment: Yep, the nologin is not defined in /etc/shells but the system recognizes it as if it were defined.

Comment: Is anything in logs (messages, security, ftpd.log)?

Comment: Apparently no, only the adduser logs.

Comment: I've checked it in my BSD instance and actually I couldn't login via ftp to created account but when I'm added /usr/sbin/nologin to /etc/shells everything started working properly